# Using L'Hopital's rule with the indeterminate form of infinity minus infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm aware that with L'Hopital's rule, we're dealing with indeterminate forms of
 $ \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} $, and that includes re-writing $\lim_{x\to a} \infty - \infty$ into that format. However, I'm not sure how to proceed with the following:

$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} {\ln3x}-{\ln(x+1)} $$

Should I take the derivative first and then simplify for L'Hopital's rule? I'm not sure where to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} {\ln3x}-{\ln(x+1)}= \lim_{x\to\infty} \ln\frac{3x}{x+1} $$
$$=\lim_{x\to\infty} \ln\frac{3}{1+1/x}=\ln3$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\ln a-\ln b=\ln(\frac{a}{b})$

Answer (score 0):

$\ln(a)-\ln(b)=\ln\frac{a}{b}$